# How to use shell script variable in mv command

Tags: shell, environment-variables, double-quotes, curly-braces

I'd like to store my path in variable in order to use with `mv` command.

```
WEBSITEPATH="/var/www/gestiaweb/mywebsitefolder/"
mv "$WEBSITEPATHcms/configs/database.json" $WEBSITEPATH
```

Error : `WEBSITEPATHcms` is interpreted as a folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, it's a good idea to wrap your shell variables with `{..}`. So, do:

```
mv "${WEBSITEPATH}cms/configs/database.json" "${WEBSITEPATH}"
```

instead. You'll note I also quoted the second use of the variable. This is generally a good idea also.

I find that the Google style guide for shell scripts is pretty good advice: https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html